# How can I add automated tag to my Docker repository?

Tags: git, github, docker

I have a github repository which is linked with automated build in docker.
But in this repository, i am releasing(tagging) new version almost everyday. And i want to add all tags to docker environment. I can add these tags manually by defining new automated build from tag.

But i want to do this automatically, when i create new tag from github, automatically new tag should created in docker repo. 
Is there any solution for this?
I can run a script for this, or can run an ant-build. I agree all solutions except doing it manually.

Comment: I think this is a specific requirement, but can't you make a script that do this, with `ant` as you mention?

Comment: @KevinSimper, I couldn't find any documentation or sample script for this work.